# Overcomplicating regular expression

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression `^(?:\/foo\/)([A-Za-z0-9-]{0,})|^(?:\/foo)` that needs to match `/foo`,`/foo/`, `/foo/abc-123` but not `/foobar`. This works, I've tested it but I'm sure there is a simpler way using something like lookbehind or ahead.

How can I simplify it, or do I need to? Maybe it's just me being over paranoid about the ugliness of it. Maybe drop the non capturing groups, to have `^\/foo\/([A-Za-z0-9-]{0,})|^\/foo` still doesn't look right

**Note** the goal is to capture `abd-123` if present, but not capture the `/` or the empty string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this simpler regex for the same purpose:

```
^\/foo(?:\/([A-Za-z0-9-]*))?$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wE9pF4/3)

Comment: I need to capture the block, so droping the ?: would be close enough, capturing the forward slash too, can I not capture it?

Comment: sure see updated regex for capturing part after `/foo/`

Comment: So I'm stuck with the empty string nonetheless, see capture group 1, I's good enough for me, cheers

Comment: Yes I just copied that part from OP, fixed now.